# ReactJs - can't access setState inside axios call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-class-based-component

I'm having troubles setting state to the variable `isCorrectAnswer` inside an axios call. I'm getting the error `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setState')` in the console log. What am I doing wrong?
Initial state of `isCorrectAnswer` variable is  `constructor(props) {super(props)this.state = { isCorrectAnswer: false }}`
and the axios call is

```
axios.post(
      "API/path/to/ressource",
      postData,
      {
        headers: {
          "X-Access-Token":
            "token",
        },
      }
    )
      .then(function (res) {
        this.setState({
          isCorrectAnswer: res.data.correct //Here im trying to change the state
        }, () => console.log(this.state.isCorrectAnswer)) //and logging into console
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
```

Comment: If you're having troubles with `this`, the answer is often that you ought to be using arrow functions instead of the function keyword. For more info, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20279485/15299500).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call a function (non arrow function), `this` is always an implicit parameter.

**Normal functions**

*By normal functions I mean functions that are not methods.*

In **strict mode** value of `this` is always `undefined`.

And in **non strict mode** value of `this` is always the global object (`window` in browsers)

```js
function foo() {
  "use strict";
  return this;
}

function bar() {
  return this;
}

console.log(foo() === undefined); // true
console.log(bar() === window); // true
```

**Methods**

`this` refers to the object on which the method has been invoked.

```js
function foo() {
  "use strict";
  return this;
}

const obj = { foo };

console.log(obj.foo() === obj); // true
```

And in your case the callback passed to `then` is a normal function (not a method), so it's `this` is set `undefined`, hence you are getting an error.

Update to an arrow function and it would solve the issue because arrow functions don't have their own `this`, in arrow functions `this` is decided on the basis of lexical scope. Checkout the example below:

```js
const getRandomNums = (delay) =>
  new Promise((res) => setTimeout(() => res([5, 2, 3]), delay));

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { nums: [] };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    getRandomNums(1500).then((nums) => {
      this.setState({ nums });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return <div>{JSON.stringify(this.state.nums, null, 2)}</div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do
Use arrow function instead of `function`

```
axios.post(
  "API/path/to/ressource",
  postData,
  {
    headers: {
      "X-Access-Token":
        "token",
    },
  }
)
  .then((res) => {
    this.setState({
      isCorrectAnswer: res.data.correct //Here im trying to change the state
    }, () => console.log(this.state.isCorrectAnswer)) //and logging into console
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```